# How to present datepicker only upon click of a button

Tags: ipad, core-data, uibutton, uidatepicker

I need to know if a date picker can be presented like an alert view upon the click of a button. So far, I have hidden the date picker in viewdidload method and set hidden=no in the method for the button.

I intend to store the date within Core Data.

Comment: This question is overly broad. Your basically asking us to write a big chunk of the app for you. Break the question down into smaller pieces e.g. "How to I display a date picker?" and "How to a get data out of date picker?" and "How to I enter a date into Core Data"

Comment: No. Basically i know how to get data out of date picker and also how to store it in core data. I just wanted to know if the date picker can be presented like an alert view on click of a button. What i have done is, i have hidden the date picker in viewdidload method and set hidden=no in the method for the button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the pickerView, place it outside of your view bounds, add it as a subview and use animation to slide it up. Something like the below should work...

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, 215);
UIPickerView *typePicker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[self.view addSubview:typePicker];
[UIView beginAnimations:@"slideIn" context:nil];
[typePicker setCenter:CGPointMake(typePicker.center.x, self.view.frame.size.height - typePicker.frame.size.height/2)];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score 0):

You put the date picker in a subview and then present the subview at the click of a button. You probably want the subview to slide in from the side or bottom.